# how can i retrieve _utma,_utmb,_utmc and _utmz cookies from a POST or GET response?

Tags: java, cookies, google-analytics

ok so i have written a java code to login to a website and retrieve the html source code of the logged in home page.
standard algorythm:
1. send a POST request to the login page with parameters and headers
2. retrieve cookie from the "Set-Cookie" header from the response
3. send a GET request with the Cookie Header

The problem is the Set-Cookie header has only one value of the form 

PHPSESSID=52b85thehieu49g7dsfrk0b1g3

but the Cookie header in the GET request accepts 5 values of the format
Cookie:__utma=214389125.1584499811.1401640205.1406616602.1406628563.33; __utmz=214389125.1401640205.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __utmb=214389125.6.10.1406628563;
PHPSESSID=52b85thehieu49g7dsfrk0b1g3;
__utmc=214389125

i believe the _utm[x] codes are from google analytics
this is the only heckle remaining
how con i generate or retrieve _utma,_utmb,_utmc,_utmz values ?
Any hints or information appreciated  thanks in advance
p.s:[The website in question](http://cuherp.chalkpad.in//Interface/index.php)

Comment: I think you are correct that they are Google Analytics codes http://goo.gl/xHKnFM .   But I have no idea how you can generate them, you might try just sending the values you see there.  It will break the sites logging of Google analytics but if its not your site you probably don't care about that.

Comment: Can you explain better what are you doing? Why are you building this and why do you need to generate the _utm* cookies?